# android activity create multiple instance of my thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, handler

i need to check a variable for change, if the change happens i will update a textview.

so i created a new thread with a while loop for this purpose. i check the variable every 1 second, via Thread.sleep()

this thread created and started in onCreate(). so it's one time.

the problem is every time i flip my phone (from vertical to horizontal or ...) a new thread will be created.

here is my code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity
{
private final static int LOAD_SUCCESSFULL = 1;
private final long LOCATION_THREAD_SLEEP = 1000;    
private boolean flag = false;   
static TextView lat;
static TextView lon;    
static Location currentLocation = null; 
Thread locationThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_home2);
    this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.new_home_titlebar);

    lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2rt3);
    lon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2rt4);

    /* FindLocation class is a helper class that find location via simcard or gps in separate thread,
        same problem happen with this thread also, it create multiple thread, for ease of work i 
        commented this part.
    */      
    //FindLocation fn = new FindLocation(this);

    locationThread = new Thread(null, loadLocation, "loadLocationHomePage");

    locationUpdater();
}

private static Handler locationUpdateHandler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch(msg.what)
        {
        case LOAD_SUCCESSFULL:
            lat.setText(Double.toString(currentLocation.getLatitude()));
            lon.setText(Double.toString(currentLocation.getLongitude()));
            //stopThread();
            break;              
        }
    }
};

private Runnable loadLocation = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //boolean flag = false;
        while(!flag)
        {
            if(Data.currLocation != null)
            {                   
                currentLocation = new Location(Data.currLocation);                  
                Message msg = locationUpdateHandler.obtainMessage(LOAD_SUCCESSFULL);                    
                locationUpdateHandler.sendMessage(msg); 
                //return;
                flag = true;
                //return;
            }               
            else
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(LOCATION_THREAD_SLEEP);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
        }
    }
};

public void locationUpdater()
{
    //Thread locationThread = new Thread(null, loadLocation, "loadLocationHomePage");
    locationThread.start();
}
```

so how i can solve this?

[image]

Comment: I think it's more useful to try to explain what you are trying to do. It seems like you're updating a global static variable (currentLocation) in another place and want to read that in this activity. Instead of using threads, it seems like you should be using some sort of mechanism to let listeners know that a new location is ready to be consumed.

Comment: @dmon: ok, you are right i update a static Location object via FindLocation class (read the comment in oncreate). then every time the location updated i want to update 2 textView, (for latitude and longitude), so i created this thread to check the availability of Location variables.

Comment: @dmon: i can not found any mechanism to do that for textview, for a listView you can do this by notify() (or something like this, i don't remember), but for text view there is nothing like this, so i do that, anyway the mechanism doesn't matter, the matter is this problem shouldn't happen at all.

Comment: What problem shouldn't happen at all?

Comment: @Pork: look at the picture in the main question. there is 3 of this thread. every time i flip my phone new thread will be created.  THIS MUST NOT HAPPEN AT ALL.

Comment: That is how android works. If you want to avoid that happening please refer to my answer, and use a headless/UIless fragment to hold your thread. A fragment will persist between rotates not need to recreate anything between rotates.

Comment: @Pork: Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0, i'm writing for android 2.2 and up. any other solution?

Comment: Fragments are usable down to 1.6. Just import the android v4 support library which is probably already imported depending on what IDE you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that EveryTime you flip the phone a new instance of `Activity` is created and because of this you on every rotation you get a call on `onCreate()` where you are blindly creating a new `Thread` and Starting the new `Thread`.

This is the default behavior of every `Activity` but we can change this re-creation of Activity by stating an attribute in `AndroidManifest` file for the Activity

```
<activity
    android:name="yourPackage.ActivityName"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
</activity>
```

This will prevent from creation of Activity on orientation change.

You will also get these orientation event if you `override`

```
@Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {}
```

Hope this will solve this problem without implementing such a complex logic which may broke in some other uses case.

Comment: I've upvoted because this is an answer, at least suitable for a beginner, but not a recommended solution.

Comment: this might work, but in this case i need to handle orientation myself.
i am thinking of creating my listener to retrieve location value.

Comment: @Pork Yes this not a recommended solution, but How you want to design your system is totally on your hand I have just given the solution that why the new instance of thread is created on every orientation change. I will also suggest you to create a LocationManager class and Make it as a singleton class so that in your whole system there should be only the one instance of this manager and every component say Activity or Services can use this instance.

Comment: @Mehdok No need to handle Orientation in this, if you want so you can else it is not mandatory joust don't override onConfigurationChanged() method. And about the listener for location you can design any your classes and interface in any ways as you want, this solution is still applicable what you have design and posted above in you question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't perhaps going about this in the most efficient way possible.

But if your question is simply, how do i prevent multiple worker threads from being spawned, you should look into a UIless fragment.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#headlessfragments1

Comment: i couldn't find any other efficient way for this problem. do you know any?

Comment: well I've answered your question. I don't really see the point of having location being polled in some other part of your app. Why not just have locationmanager and the locationlistener in your activity or perhaps again, a headerless fragment?

Comment: there is 5 activities that need this information, if i use locationmanager in every activity, so every activity trying to find location, so i create that separate class, and do this once, so every other activity can use this info.
the other problem is reading location via GPS is time consuming process, with my way user can navigate other activity while gps loading location in background.

Comment: There is no harm in doing it in each activity, put the code into a parent activity class to make it neater.

Comment: suppose i start an activity, and activity start finding location, user click on something and new activity will be started, the new activity also trying to find location (register new listener and all the work again), and so on. is this gona to make any problem? ( i think it slow down the app like hell) if you need i will post my code for finding location.

Comment: It's not really a problem. The only duplication in computing time is whatever it is you are doing once you get the location.

Did you find the answer was accurate, I would appreciate a vote? IF you have other questions you should post them new.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why android doing this. if i putted my code in onResume(), then this behavior make sence but in my case, i don't know.

anyway i found a dirty solution. the idea is finding list of all thread and search them for mine, if it existed prevent to create another.

```
public boolean checkThreadExist()
{
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
    for(int i = 0; i < threadArray.length ; i++)
    {
        if(threadArray[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("loadLocationHomePage"))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

updated onCreate() :

```
if(checkThreadExist())
    {

    }
    else
    {
        locationThread = new Thread(null, loadLocation, "loadLocationHomePage");            
        locationUpdater();            
    }
```

Comment: onCreate is called whenever a configuration change occurs, when you rotate your phone, the entire activity is destroyed and created from scratch. It's normal behaviour. If you want to retain something, use onSaveInstanceState() and during oncreate savedInstanceState will have your data from the previously destroyed activity... OR... you use a fragment (the recommended solution if you are doing "work" that should persist.